# are 2 circuits possible in a 12awg x 4 extension cord?

Tags: wiring

is it possible to run 2 fused/breaker circuits 110-120V in a 12 awg x 4  95' extension cord with 2 plugs @ ea. end? green, black, white, red. or 'd the black need to be 10 awg?

thanks,
:o)))

Comment: What will be your power source that you are plugging in to?

Comment: Also, what amperage?  The gauge of the wire is based on how much current you need.

Comment: Black and red will be both hot/live wires and should be same gauge.  Use only one double breaker.  My generator extension cord is set up this way, plugs into a 30amp outlet and has 4 120v outlet to plug stuff into.  For temporary use only.

Comment: For emphasis: **For temporary use only.** _– crip659 28 mins ago_

Comment: Reading your question again, can only use one plug to connect to a single power source.  Can have two or more outlets at other end as shown in @Greg Hill answer.

Comment: The question seems loaded.  Of course two circuits are "possible", and it's not clear what you are wanting to do, or why, or what your question really is.  You cannot *buy* a cord made the way you describe.  And if you are going to *make* one, why not make one in a way that correctly addresses the unstated questions?  Why not use two ordinary extension cords?  Do you have a spare piece of 12/3 cable, and you need 30A of 120V power 90 feet away from where you have two regular 120V outlets, right next to each other, that you know are on different phases, so you want to achieve this for $0?

Answer (score 3):

A "multi-wire branch circuit" can provide two 120 volt circuits using 4 conductors (it also simultaneously provides 240 volts, which may or may not be valuable to you).

An off-the-shelf solution is to use an extension cord with L14-30 connectors on both ends followed by an L14-30 to 5-20R breakout "generator adapter" cable. It wouldn't have to be powered by a generator; you could arrange an L14-30 receptacle powered by mains for it. That can be protected by a 20A two-pole breaker so that you don't have to worry about having excessive current available at the 20-amp sockets of the breakout/adapter cable.

[image: L14-30 extension cable]

[image: generator adapter cable]

Comment: Did you snatch those pics off Amazon or eBay listings? If so please do not use pictures (or recommend) cheap Chinese products sold by third parties, i.e. "Sold by (someone other than Amazon)" whether or not it ships with Prime. For instance the lower cable is illegal for sale in the US (no fuses, you can plainly see since it's transparent).

Comment: But other than that, yes, your idea is on track, and I'm not writing an answer because you covered it.  On a 20A version of that cord (which is what OP is after), UL will approve cords like that without fuses.

Comment: well, I'm not writing that answer.

Comment: This is why the power source OP has is important.  If it comes from a double pole breaker that's fine, but you can't just pick to separate breakers and hope that it works.  If they are on the same 120v phase, the neutral will be overloaded.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica That definitely happens a lot! In this instance I do own one of that green extension cord. Seems to be good and durable quality, and IIRC it at least has a foil tag that _looks_ like a legit UL label. The yellow cord is sold by Champion as an accessory for their generators here in the US. I'm not sure how they get away with the lack of fusing though. Maybe its fine print says it's only for use on generators that can't make more than 20A anyway, despite the L14-30 connector...

Comment: @Greg or I could be wrong and the fuses are in the plug end. I know many people counterfeit UL marks, but I haven't seen many cases of it in Amazon/eBay fodder, they usually are content to fake CE.   I suspect UL has a very busy legal office in China.

Comment: @GregHill  Have similar extension from Champion, but mine has round cable, do think mine does have protection(small buttons neat outlets end).

Answer (score 3):

### There can be only one... *plug*

You're talking about having 2 plugs on one end, and 2 sockets on the other.  (in other words you are trying to use "suicide cords" to get 240V from 2 different 120V circuits).  That is illegal as the day is long, for obvious "kill people" reasons.

Your logic is "the unplugged plug shouldn't be harmful because it doesn't connect to the other plug's hot wire" - yes, but it connects to the other plug's *neutral* wire, and neutral is lethal *unless everything is working properly*.    That's why we use insulated wires for it.

Also, there's no guarantee you'd plug them into circuits on opposite phases... if both circuits were on the same phase, neutral is being overloaded!

So no.

Also it's not cost effective.  What you need is two 120V extension cords.  Those are commodity items and cheap.  What you're trying to do is exotic and costly, even if you already own the 12/4 cordage.

Also, remember, cords are only for temporary (e.g. day-use) wiring. It is not a substitute for permanently installed wiring. If you are trying to run power to a shed or the like, then install a proper installation using direct burial or conduit buried at legal depths.

Comment: I totally missed that OP wanted 2 plugs at the source end. I'm glad you addressed why that's a no-go!